# RSI trail pinescript

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I need help in RSI pinescript= lets suppose price of 'X'  is $6000, and it rises to $7000 and RSI also goes above band70. Now i want alert gets activated when it drops to $6980(i.e. gets trail back by $20). How can i code this TRAIL script in RSI pinescript.

```
 //@version=4
study("rsi overbought", overlay=true)

rsiSource = input(title="RSI Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
rsiLength = input(title="RSI Length", type=input.integer, defval=14)
rsiOverbought = input(title="RSI Overbought Level", type=input.integer, defval=70)


rsiValue = rsi(rsiSource, rsiLength)
isRsiOB = rsiValue >= rsiOverbought


plotshape(isRsiOB, title="Overbought", location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, text="Sell")

alertcondition(isRsiOB , title="RSI Signal!", message="RSI Signal Detected for {{ticker}}")
```

Comment: Create a variable using valuewhen(crossover(rsi,70),0). Then give condition that close > that variable -20 to give signal, which can be plotted as shape on chart.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
trail_high = highest(high,20) //highest high of 20 bars

down_num = 20 //the trailing 20$

if( low < trail_high - down_num)
    alert_code
```

PS this will trigger after the candle has closed

Answer (score 0):

The same thing which is mentioned above can someone make this in Calgo.
My Strategy is that buy only when the RSI line crosses the 30 RSI from below.

and vice versa for RSI 70 when crossed from above then sell.